# Does a conditional statement stop executing if something within the statement causes that conditional to no longer be true/false?

Tags: c++, syntax

The following is C++ code, probably important to emphasize!

For example, what I mean is, say I have:

```
bool this = true;
if(this)
{
   this = false;
   //other code here
}
```

When "this" becomes false, does that mean the statements within the conditional will no longer execute, since the conditions are no longer being met, or will the rest of the statement "//other code here" still be executed? I have been careful not to change the state of a conditional until I am done doing whatever it is I need to do with that conditional, but am curious if this is necessary in the first place. Thanks for your time.

Comment: of course it doesn't. But consider that before posting such a simple question you should have done your own research.

Comment: 'this' is a keyword in C++.  The code above won't even compile.

Comment: Why not try it ? Experimentation isn't that bad !

Comment: No. The code example you show executes sequentially (a fundamental property of the language). Once the `if` is evaluated and you enter the `if` contents, it doesn't revisit the `if`. Where you would need to be careful is a loop construct such as `for` or `while`, etc. In those cases, the repeat occurs until the condition is no longer met for execution.

Comment: @StefanoFalasca Thanks for your informative and productive putdown. I'm aware of 'this' as a reserved keyword and should have used something else, my apologies. Otherwise, thanks for your replies!

Comment: *The following is C++ code*. No, it isn't. You cannot name a variable `this`, as it is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the condition in your statement is tested at the point where it says `if(this)` [1] - after that, you can change the value anyway you like, and the code will continue.

Note that this concept ALSO holds true for `while(condition) { ... }` - the `condition` is only chcked at the beginning of the loop, so the code continues sequentially from there, until it goes back to the beginning of the loop again.

It is a fairly common pattern to do this:

```
need_print_heading = true;
lines = 0;

while(more_data)
{

    if (need_print_heading)
    {
       need_print_heading = false;
       print_heading();
    }
    print_data();
    linex++;
    if (lines > 50) need_print_heading = true;
}
```

[1] Use of `this` in the code you are showing means that it's invalid C++, since `this` is a reserved word in C++. You need to change the name to make this code compile.

Comment: I'm aware of this as a reserved keyword and should have used a better one. Thanks for the reply.